# API call not being made as it is not reflecting in the network tab in Google chrome developer tools

Tags: angular, api, google-chrome

I am trying to make a call to a recipe API, parse the response and then show it in the HTML. Here is the code:

display-recipes.component.html

```
<p>display-recipes works!</p>
<div id='display_recipe'  *ngFor="let recipe of recipeResult.hits">
    {{calories}}  {{recipe}}
</div>
```

display-recipes.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { SearchRecipeService } from '../search-recipe.service';
import { RecipeGlobal } from '../pojos/RecipeGlobal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-recipes',
  templateUrl: './display-recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-recipes.component.css']
})
export class DisplayRecipesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() calories: String;
  @Input() recipe: String;
  recipeResult: RecipeGlobal;
  constructor(private searchRecipeService: SearchRecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipeResult = new RecipeGlobal();
    this.getRecipeInfo();

  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.getRecipeInfo();
  }

  getRecipeInfo(){
     this.searchRecipeService.getRecipeInfo().
     subscribe(recipeResult => this.recipeResult = recipeResult);
  }

}
```

search-recipe.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RecipeGlobal, Recipe } from './pojos/RecipeGlobal';
import { Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchRecipeService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {}

    private searchUrl = 'https://api.edamam.com/search?q=bandejapaisa&app_id=xxxx&app_key=xxxxxxx&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free';

  getRecipeInfo(): Observable<RecipeGlobal>{
         return this.http.get<RecipeGlobal>(this.searchUrl)
         .pipe(

           catchError(_ => {console.log("error"); return [];})
         );
  }


}
```

RecipeGlobal.ts -> mapping mojo for the API response

```
export class RecipeGlobal{
    q!: String;
    hits!: Recipe[];
}

export class Recipe{
    image: String;
    calories: String;
    label: String
}
```

The response from the API call should be this:

{

```
  "q": "bandeja paisa",
  "from": 0,
  "to": 3,
  "more": false,
  "count": 1,
  "hits": [
    {
      "recipe": {
        "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_023ae14ca70ba202bfa5dddfd60564a8",
        "label": "Bandeja Paisa",
        "image": "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/e7e/e7e5236b4b1c067c881c25004ee9e239.jpg",
        "source": "My Recipes",
        "url": "http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/bandeja-paisa",
        "shareAs": "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/bandeja-paisa-023ae14ca70ba202bfa5dddfd60564a8/bandeja+paisa/alcohol-free/591-722-cal",
        "yield": 4.0,
        "dietLabels": [
          "Low-Carb"
        ],
        "healthLabels": [
          "Sugar-Conscious",
          "Peanut-Free",
          "Tree-Nut-Free",
          "Alcohol-Free"
        ],
        "cautions": [],
        "ingredientLines": [
          "1 pound skinless pork belly",
          "2 teaspoons kosher salt",
          "2 teaspoons granulated sugar",
          "1/2 teaspoon ground cumin"
        ],
        "ingredients": [
          {
            "text": "1 pound skinless pork belly",
            "weight": 453.59237
          },
          {
            "text": "2 teaspoons kosher salt",
            "weight": 9.70833333382575
          },
          {
            "text": "2 teaspoons granulated sugar",
            "weight": 8.4
          },
          {
            "text": "1/2 teaspoon ground cumin",
            "weight": 1.05
          }
        ],
        "calories": 2386.0539766,
        "totalWeight": 465.4413539831457,
        "totalTime": 780.0,
        "totalNutrients": {
          "ENERC_KCAL": {
            "label": "Energy",
            "quantity": 2386.0539766,
            "unit": "kcal"
          },
          "FAT": {
            "label": "Fat",
            "quantity": 240.68315033700003,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "FASAT": {
            "label": "Saturated",
            "quantity": 87.695522621,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "FAMS": {
            "label": "Monounsaturated",
            "quantity": 112.18473539000001,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "FAPU": {
            "label": "Polyunsaturated",
            "quantity": 25.662398405000005,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "CHOCDF": {
            "label": "Carbs",
            "quantity": 8.86284,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "FIBTG": {
            "label": "Fiber",
            "quantity": 0.11025,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "SUGAR": {
            "label": "Sugars",
            "quantity": 8.406825,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "SUGAR.added": {
            "label": "Sugars, added",
            "quantity": 8.3832,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "PROCNT": {
            "label": "Protein",
            "quantity": 42.552532358,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "CHOLE": {
            "label": "Cholesterol",
            "quantity": 326.5865064,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "NA": {
            "label": "Sodium",
            "quantity": 1076.7957705876,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "CA": {
            "label": "Calcium",
            "quantity": 33.114874655954964,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "MG": {
            "label": "Magnesium",
            "quantity": 22.01068463983146,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "K": {
            "label": "Potassium",
            "quantity": 858.2798032186518,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "FE": {
            "label": "Iron",
            "quantity": 3.0675769711443808,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "ZN": {
            "label": "Zinc",
            "quantity": 4.6802811579831465,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "P": {
            "label": "Phosphorus",
            "quantity": 495.1192596000001,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "VITA_RAE": {
            "label": "Vitamin A",
            "quantity": 14.279771100000001,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          "VITC": {
            "label": "Vitamin C",
            "quantity": 1.4416271100000002,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "THIA": {
            "label": "Thiamin (B1)",
            "quantity": 1.8028197852000003,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "RIBF": {
            "label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
            "quantity": 1.1027230354000002,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "NIA": {
            "label": "Niacin (B3)",
            "quantity": 21.126516933900003,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "VITB6A": {
            "label": "Vitamin B6",
            "quantity": 0.594237581,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "FOLDFE": {
            "label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
            "quantity": 4.640923700000001,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          "FOLFD": {
            "label": "Folate (food)",
            "quantity": 4.640923700000001,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          "VITB12": {
            "label": "Vitamin B12",
            "quantity": 3.810175908,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          "TOCPHA": {
            "label": "Vitamin E",
            "quantity": 1.8039752430000002,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          "VITK1": {
            "label": "Vitamin K",
            "quantity": 0.05670000000000001,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          "WATER": {
            "label": "Water",
            "quantity": 166.7409447059663,
            "unit": "g"
          }
        },
        "totalDaily": {
          "ENERC_KCAL": {
            "label": "Energy",
            "quantity": 119.30269883000001,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "FAT": {
            "label": "Fat",
            "quantity": 370.2817697492308,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "FASAT": {
            "label": "Saturated",
            "quantity": 438.477613105,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "CHOCDF": {
            "label": "Carbs",
            "quantity": 2.95428,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "FIBTG": {
            "label": "Fiber",
            "quantity": 0.441,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "PROCNT": {
            "label": "Protein",
            "quantity": 85.105064716,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "CHOLE": {
            "label": "Cholesterol",
            "quantity": 108.8621688,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "NA": {
            "label": "Sodium",
            "quantity": 44.86649044115,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "CA": {
            "label": "Calcium",
            "quantity": 3.3114874655954964,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "MG": {
            "label": "Magnesium",
            "quantity": 5.240639199959872,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "K": {
            "label": "Potassium",
            "quantity": 18.261272408907484,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "FE": {
            "label": "Iron",
            "quantity": 17.042094284135448,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "ZN": {
            "label": "Zinc",
            "quantity": 42.548010527119516,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "P": {
            "label": "Phosphorus",
            "quantity": 70.73132280000002,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "VITA_RAE": {
            "label": "Vitamin A",
            "quantity": 1.5866412333333333,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "VITC": {
            "label": "Vitamin C",
            "quantity": 1.6018079000000003,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "THIA": {
            "label": "Thiamin (B1)",
            "quantity": 150.23498210000002,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "RIBF": {
            "label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
            "quantity": 84.82484887692308,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "NIA": {
            "label": "Niacin (B3)",
            "quantity": 132.040730836875,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "VITB6A": {
            "label": "Vitamin B6",
            "quantity": 45.71058315384615,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "FOLDFE": {
            "label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
            "quantity": 1.1602309250000002,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "VITB12": {
            "label": "Vitamin B12",
            "quantity": 158.7573295,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "TOCPHA": {
            "label": "Vitamin E",
            "quantity": 12.026501620000001,
            "unit": "%"
          },
          "VITK1": {
            "label": "Vitamin K",
            "quantity": 0.04725000000000001,
            "unit": "%"
          }
        },
        "digest": [
          {
            "label": "Fat",
            "tag": "FAT",
            "schemaOrgTag": "fatContent",
            "total": 240.68315033700003,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 370.2817697492308,
            "unit": "g",
            "sub": [
              {
                "label": "Saturated",
                "tag": "FASAT",
                "schemaOrgTag": "saturatedFatContent",
                "total": 87.695522621,
                "hasRDI": true,
                "daily": 438.477613105,
                "unit": "g"
              },
              {
                "label": "Trans",
                "tag": "FATRN",
                "schemaOrgTag": "transFatContent",
                "total": 0.0,
                "hasRDI": false,
                "daily": 0.0,
                "unit": "g"
              },
              {
                "label": "Monounsaturated",
                "tag": "FAMS",
                "schemaOrgTag": null,
                "total": 112.18473539000001,
                "hasRDI": false,
                "daily": 0.0,
                "unit": "g"
              },
              {
                "label": "Polyunsaturated",
                "tag": "FAPU",
                "schemaOrgTag": null,
                "total": 25.662398405000005,
                "hasRDI": false,
                "daily": 0.0,
                "unit": "g"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "Carbs",
            "tag": "CHOCDF",
            "schemaOrgTag": "carbohydrateContent",
            "total": 8.86284,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 2.95428,
            "unit": "g",
            "sub": [
              {
                "label": "Carbs (net)",
                "tag": "CHOCDF.net",
                "schemaOrgTag": null,
                "total": 8.75259,
                "hasRDI": false,
                "daily": 0.0,
                "unit": "g"
              },
              {
                "label": "Fiber",
                "tag": "FIBTG",
                "schemaOrgTag": "fiberContent",
                "total": 0.11025,
                "hasRDI": true,
                "daily": 0.441,
                "unit": "g"
              },
              {
                "label": "Sugars",
                "tag": "SUGAR",
                "schemaOrgTag": "sugarContent",
                "total": 8.406825,
                "hasRDI": false,
                "daily": 0.0,
                "unit": "g"
              },
              {
                "label": "Sugars, added",
                "tag": "SUGAR.added",
                "schemaOrgTag": null,
                "total": 8.3832,
                "hasRDI": false,
                "daily": 0.0,
                "unit": "g"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "Protein",
            "tag": "PROCNT",
            "schemaOrgTag": "proteinContent",
            "total": 42.552532358,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 85.105064716,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          {
            "label": "Cholesterol",
            "tag": "CHOLE",
            "schemaOrgTag": "cholesterolContent",
            "total": 326.5865064,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 108.8621688,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Sodium",
            "tag": "NA",
            "schemaOrgTag": "sodiumContent",
            "total": 1076.7957705876,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 44.86649044115,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Calcium",
            "tag": "CA",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 33.114874655954964,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 3.3114874655954964,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Magnesium",
            "tag": "MG",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 22.01068463983146,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 5.240639199959872,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Potassium",
            "tag": "K",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 858.2798032186518,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 18.261272408907484,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Iron",
            "tag": "FE",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 3.0675769711443808,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 17.042094284135448,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Zinc",
            "tag": "ZN",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 4.6802811579831465,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 42.548010527119516,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Phosphorus",
            "tag": "P",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 495.1192596000001,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 70.73132280000002,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Vitamin A",
            "tag": "VITA_RAE",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 14.279771100000001,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 1.5866412333333333,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Vitamin C",
            "tag": "VITC",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 1.4416271100000002,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 1.6018079000000003,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Thiamin (B1)",
            "tag": "THIA",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 1.8028197852000003,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 150.23498210000002,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
            "tag": "RIBF",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 1.1027230354000002,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 84.82484887692308,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Niacin (B3)",
            "tag": "NIA",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 21.126516933900003,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 132.040730836875,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Vitamin B6",
            "tag": "VITB6A",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 0.594237581,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 45.71058315384615,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
            "tag": "FOLDFE",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 4.640923700000001,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 1.1602309250000002,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Folate (food)",
            "tag": "FOLFD",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 4.640923700000001,
            "hasRDI": false,
            "daily": 0.0,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Folic acid",
            "tag": "FOLAC",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 0.0,
            "hasRDI": false,
            "daily": 0.0,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Vitamin B12",
            "tag": "VITB12",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 3.810175908,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 158.7573295,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Vitamin D",
            "tag": "VITD",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 0.0,
            "hasRDI": false,
            "daily": 0.0,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Vitamin E",
            "tag": "TOCPHA",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 1.8039752430000002,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 12.026501620000001,
            "unit": "mg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Vitamin K",
            "tag": "VITK1",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 0.05670000000000001,
            "hasRDI": true,
            "daily": 0.04725000000000001,
            "unit": "µg"
          },
          {
            "label": "Sugar alcohols",
            "tag": "Sugar.alcohol",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 0.0,
            "hasRDI": false,
            "daily": 0.0,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          {
            "label": "Water",
            "tag": "WATER",
            "schemaOrgTag": null,
            "total": 166.7409447059663,
            "hasRDI": false,
            "daily": 0.0,
            "unit": "g"
          }
        ]
      },
      "bookmarked": false,
      "bought": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I am just parsing a few elements in the response by using the mentioned POJO class above. I am seeing the component is loading properly from the parent component but it's not displaying data inside the div as the API call is not being made. I am seeing the error log displayed in the console but the API call is not showing up in the network tab.

Comment: Your response type and class definition are completely different. Are you mapping (converting) the raw response to class definition somewhere?

Comment: @ShadabFaiz no. That's the only place. I expect the response to be parsed properly in the service method. I then fetch it from the component method inside subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

You have some misunderstandings regarding the classes in typescript. Classes in the typescript are not some magic. You have only defined the class and expect the angular to automatically map the raw response to the actual class structure. They don't. You have to manually map the raw response to the actual class defined structure.

```js
  getRecipeInfo(): Observable<RecipeGlobal>{
         return this.http.get<RecipeGlobal>(this.searchUrl)
         .pipe(
           map(res => this.mapRawResponse(res))
           catchError(_ => {console.log("error"); return [];})
         );
  }

    private mapRawResponse(rawResponse): RecipeGlobal {
          //... your code to map the response to Recipe.
    }
```

If you don't want to map the response, then change the structure of your class definition to match the raw response.

As for the no API calls being shown in the Network tab, check the filters on it, you may using some filters (css/Img/Media/etc). Switch it to xhr/All to see.

**Updated with proper class**
Use this class instead to get the type support:

```js
export interface RecipeGlobal {
    q:     string;
    from:  number;
    to:    number;
    more:  boolean;
    count: number;
    hits:  Hit[];
}

export interface Hit {
    recipe:     Recipe;
    bookmarked: boolean;
    bought:     boolean;
}

export interface Recipe {
    uri:             string;
    label:           string;
    image:           string;
    source:          string;
    url:             string;
    shareAs:         string;
    yield:           number;
    dietLabels:      string[];
    healthLabels:    string[];
    cautions:        any[];
    ingredientLines: string[];
    ingredients:     Ingredient[];
    calories:        number;
    totalWeight:     number;
    totalTime:       number;
    totalNutrients:  { [key: string]: Total };
    totalDaily:      { [key: string]: Total };
    digest:          Digest[];
}

export interface Digest {
    label:        string;
    tag:          string;
    schemaOrgTag: null | string;
    total:        number;
    hasRDI:       boolean;
    daily:        number;
    unit:         Unit;
    sub?:         Digest[];
}

export enum Unit {
    Empty = "%",
    G = "g",
    Kcal = "kcal",
    Mg = "mg",
    Μg = "µg",
}

export interface Ingredient {
    text:   string;
    weight: number;
}

export interface Total {
    label:    string;
    quantity: number;
    unit:     Unit;
}
```

Comment: Hi Shabad. When you say class definition, do you mean change the structure of the pojo the match the raw response? And also I am seeing the error log in console.

Comment: By class definition, I mean how you have structured the properties of Recipe and RecipeGlobal. I'll update my answer with proper structure. You can use that. As for the log error, what are those errors?

Comment: In case something happened, I put that error in the catchError block. I assume if the request is successful the catch error block is not executed, And regarding the network tab, even if I switch to all, the API call is not there.

Comment: In this line, this.recipeResult = new RecipeGlobal(), I am getting. RecipeGlobal only refers to a type but is being used as a value instead.

Comment: Actually O am now getting a different error. I am getting a 404 in the console logs and the call doesn't show up in the network tab. The request works from postman though. It's a get request with no headers just the URL.

Comment: Now it is working. I was following the tutorial heroes app tour and installed the in memory API which intercepted all http requests hence it failed.